# ubuntu17.10 modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found in directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-35-generic

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, modprobe

```
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found in directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-35-generic
```

Reinstalled dkms but I still get

Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module by executing

'modprobe vboxdrv'

Ran `find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -name vboxdrv.ko`

Output:

```
beastly@Beastly:~$ find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -name vboxdrv.ko
beastly@Beastly:~$
```

Ran

```
beastly@Beastly:~$ sudo apt-cache policy virtualbox
```

Output:

```
virtualbox:
  Installed: 5.1.30-dfsg-1
  Candidate: 5.1.30-dfsg-1
  Version table:
 *** 5.1.30-dfsg-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/multiverse amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Ran

```
beastly@Beastly:~$ dkms status
```

Output:

```
virtualbox, 5.1.30, 4.13.0-16-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Ran

```
beastly@Beastly:~$ (uname -r)
```

Output:

```
4.10.0-35-generic
```

Comment: Could you try ```find /lib/modules/$(uname -r)  -name "vboxdrv.ko"``` and post the output?

Comment: `dkms status` please too.

Comment: What is the output of `$(uname -r)`?

Comment: Kove: It appears that you have created two accounts. Please go to [the Contact page](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles.”

Comment: I'm a little bit confused.  Why don't you boot the newest Kernel `4.13.0-16-generic` there virtualboxmodul is compiled and in the Kernel.  Let me guess this is an ugrade installation.  Plese dont tell from xenial.

Comment: I didn't know I could. I'm fairly new to Linux but I'm learning fast and enjoying it.

Answer (score 2):

@ Bahamut. Thank you.

After upgrade from Zesty to Artful, my machine was booting from and older kernel, hence the incompatibility.

```
sudo reboot
```

Hit escape and select advance options.

Selected the newest kernel
Installed compatible ext pack

```
 sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ext-pack
```

VirtualBox runs pristine.

Comment: if not on system `sudo apt install linux-generic`

Answer (score 0):

Solutions mentioned above - had not helped me (within (X)ubuntu 18.04, with the recently updated kernel). What worked in my case:

1. Setup key with:

`wget -q -O - http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox_2016.asc | sudo apt-key add -`

2. Setup repository with:

`sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian cosmic non-free contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.org.list'`

3. Download and install the latest version (with all the extra packages related to the VirtualBox) from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads